# C++ after reading from file memory fail

Tags: c++, file-io

I've got a problem with reading configuration from file in my code. Method which reads configuration looks like this :

```
void Configuration::readConfiguration()
{
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream configFile;
    ConfigurationOptions * confOpt = new ConfigurationOptions();
    InterpretateStrategy * doStrategy;
    configFile.open("configuration");

    if(!configFile.is_open())
    {
        throw "File opening error!";
    }

    configFile >> line;
    while ( line.size() != 0 )
    {
        doStrategy = this->strategyMap[line];
        doStrategy->interpretate(&configFile , confOpt);
        line.clear();
        configFile >> line;
    }

    this->connectionConfigure = new ConnectionConfigure(confOpt->getPortNumber(),
                                                    confOpt->getBufferSize());

    this->databaseConfigure = new DataBaseConfigure(confOpt->getCellName(),
                                                confOpt->getCellUser(),
                                                confOpt->getAnonymousName(),
                                                confOpt->getAnonymousUser());

    this->interpreterConfigure = new InterpreterConfigure(confOpt->getWriteRawData(),
                                                  confOpt->getWriteInterpretatedData(),
                                                  confOpt->getTransactionSize());

    delete(confOpt);
    configFile.close();
}
```

And when it execute and then threads are starting program fails with this output :

```
*** glibc detected *** ./eventReporter: free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000003c813540a8 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3c8107164f]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x4b)[0x3c8107587b]
./eventReporter[0x404cc9]
./eventReporter[0x404a22]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x3ced80683d]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x3c810d4f8d]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-0041b000 r-xp 00000000 08:08 1307697                            /home/przemek/eventReporter/eventReporter
0061b000-0061c000 rw-p 0001b000 08:08 1307697                            /home/przemek/eventReporter/eventReporter
148ef000-14910000 rw-p 148ef000 00:00 0
3c80c00000-3c80c1c000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 992032                         /lib64/ld-2.5.so
3c80e1c000-3c80e1d000 r--p 0001c000 08:02 992032                         /lib64/ld-2.5.so
3c80e1d000-3c80e1e000 rw-p 0001d000 08:02 992032                         /lib64/ld-2.5.so
3c81000000-3c8114f000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 992072                         /lib64/libc-2.5.so
3c8114f000-3c8134e000 ---p 0014f000 08:02 992072                         /lib64/libc-2.5.so
3c8134e000-3c81352000 r--p 0014e000 08:02 992072                         /lib64/libc-2.5.so
3c81352000-3c81353000 rw-p 00152000 08:02 992072                         /lib64/libc-2.5.so
3c81353000-3c81358000 rw-p 3c81353000 00:00 0
3c81400000-3c81482000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 992601                         /lib64/libm-2.5.so
3c81482000-3c81681000 ---p 00082000 08:02 992601                         /lib64/libm-2.5.so
3c81681000-3c81682000 r--p 00081000 08:02 992601                         /lib64/libm-2.5.so
3c81682000-3c81683000 rw-p 00082000 08:02 992601                         /lib64/libm-2.5.so
3c81800000-3c81802000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 992599                         /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
3c81802000-3c81a02000 ---p 00002000 08:02 992599                         /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
3c81a02000-3c81a03000 r--p 00002000 08:02 992599                         /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
3c81a03000-3c81a04000 rw-p 00003000 08:02 992599                         /lib64/libdl-2.5.so
3c81c00000-3c81c14000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 992607                         /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3c81c14000-3c81e13000 ---p 00014000 08:02 992607                         /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3c81e13000-3c81e14000 rw-p 00013000 08:02 992607                         /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3c88000000-3c8803b000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 992604                         /lib64/libsepol.so.1
3c8803b000-3c8823b000 ---p 0003b000 08:02 992604                         /lib64/libsepol.so.1
3c8823b000-3c8823c000 rw-p 0003b000 08:02 992604                         /lib64/libsepol.so.1
3c8823c000-3c88246000 rw-p 3c8823c000 00:00 0
3c88800000-3c88815000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 992605                         /lib64/libselinux.so.1
3c88815000-3c88a15000 ---p 00015000 08:02 992605                         /lib64/libselinux.so.1
3c88a15000-3c88a17000 rw-p 00015000 08:02 992605                         /lib64/libselinux.so.1
3c88a17000-3c88a18000 rw-p 3c88a17000 00:00 0
3c89600000-3c89615000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 992598                         /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
3c89615000-3c89814000 ---p 00015000 08:02 992598                         /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
3c89814000-3c89815000 r--p 00014000 08:02 992598                         /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
3c89815000-3c89816000 rw-p 00015000 08:02 992598                         /lib64/libnsl-2.5.so
3c89816000-3c89818000 rw-p 3c89816000 00:00 0
3c89a00000-3c89b2d000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 992608                         /lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
3c89b2d000-3c89d2c000 ---p 0012d000 08:02 992608                         /lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
3c89d2c000-3c89d4d000 rw-p 0012c000 08:02 992608                         /lib64/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
3c89d4d000-3c89d51000 rw-p 3c89d4d000 00:00 0
3c8a200000-3c8a202000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 992602                         /lib64/libkeyutils-1.2.so
3c8a202000-3c8a401000 ---p 00002000 08:02 992602                         /lib64/libkeyutils-1.2.so
3c8a401000-3c8a402000 rw-p 00001000 08:02 992602                         /lib64/libkeyutils-1.2.so
3c8aa00000-3c8aa11000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 992603                         /lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
3c8aa11000-3c8ac11000 ---p 00011000 08:02 992603                         /lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
3c8ac11000-3c8ac12000 r--p 00011000 08:02 992603                         /lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
3c8ac12000-3c8ac13000 rw-p 00012000 08:02 992603                         /lib64/libresolv-2.5.so
3c8ac13000-3c8ac15000 rw-p 3c8ac13000 00:00 0
3c8ba00000-3c8ba02000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 992606                         /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
3c8ba02000-3c8bc01000 ---p 00002000 08:02 992606                         /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
3c8bc01000-3c8bc02000 rw-p 00001000 08:02 992606                         /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
3c8be00000-3c8be91000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1526092                        /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
3c8be91000-3c8c091000 ---p 00091000 08:07 1526092                        /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
3c8c091000-3c8c095000 rw-p 00091000 08:07 1526092                        /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
3c8c600000-3c8c60d000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 992615                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
3c8c60d000-3c8c80d000 ---p 0000d000 08:02 992615                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
3c8c80d000-3c8c80e000 rw-p 0000d000 08:02 992615                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.1.2-20080825.so.1
3c8ca00000-3c8ca2c000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1526093                        /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
3c8ca2c000-3c8cc2c000 ---p 0002c000 08:07 1526093                        /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
3c8cc2c000-3c8cc2e000 rw-p 0002c000 08:07 1526093                        /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
3c8ce00000-3c8ce08000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1525508                        /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
3c8ce08000-3c8d007000 ---p 00008000 08:07 1525508                        /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
3c8d007000-3c8d008000 rw-p 00007000 08:07 1525508                        /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0.1
3c8d200000-3c8d224000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1526091                        /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
3c8d224000-3c8d423000 ---p 00024000 08:07 1526091                        /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
3c8d423000-3c8d425000 rw-p 00023000 08:07 1526091                        /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3.1
3c8e200000-3c8e248000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 992609                         /lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8e
3c8e248000-3c8e448000 ---p 00048000 08:02 992609                         /lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8e
3c8e448000-3c8e44e000 rw-p 00048000 08:02 992609                         /lib64/libssl.so.0.9.8e
3c8fa00000-3c8fae6000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1525245                        /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
3c8fae6000-3c8fce5000 ---p 000e6000 08:07 1525245                        /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
3c8fce5000-3c8fceb000 r--p 000e5000 08:07 1525245                        /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
3c8fceb000-3c8fcee000 rw-p 000eb000 08:07 1525245                        /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.8
3c8fcee000-3c8fd00000 rw-p 3c8fcee000 00:00 0
3c91200000-3c91209000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 992600                         /lib64/libcrypt-2.5.so
3c91209000-3c91408000 ---p 00009000 08:02 992600                         /lib64/libcrypt-2.5.so
3c91408000-3c91409000 r--p 00008000 08:02 992600                         /lib64/libcrypt-2.5.so
3c91409000-3c9140a000 rw-p 00009000 08:02 992600                         /lib64/libcrypt-2.5.so
3c9140a000-3c91438000 rw-p 3c9140a000 00:00 0
3ced800000-3ced816000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 992010                         /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
3ced816000-3ceda16000 ---p 00016000 08:02 992010                         /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
3ceda16000-3ceda17000 r--p 00016000 08:02 992010                         /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
3ceda17000-3ceda18000 rw-p 00017000 08:02 992010                         /lib64/libpthread-2.5.so
3ceda18000-3ceda1c000 rw-p 3ceda18000 00:00 0
3d02200000-3d02220000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1525745                        /usr/lib64/libpq.so.4.1
3d02220000-3d02420000 ---p 00020000 08:07 1525745                        /usr/lib64/libpq.so.4.1
3d02420000-3d02422000 rw-p 00020000 08:07 1525745                        /usr/lib64/libpq.so.4.1
2b9553d74000-2b9553d76000 rw-p 2b9553d74000 00:00 0
2b9553d8c000-2b9553ddf000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1524951                    /usr/lib64/libpqxx-2.6.9.so
2b9553ddf000-2b9553fdf000 ---p 00053000 08:07 1524951                    /usr/lib64/libpqxx-2.6.9.so
2b9553fdf000-2b9553fe2000 rw-p 00053000 08:07 1524951                    /usr/lib64/libpqxx-2.6.9.so
2b9553fe2000-2b9553feb000 rw-p 2b9553fe2000 00:00 0
2b9553feb000-2b9553fec000 ---p 2b9553feb000 00:00 0
2b9553fec000-2b95549ec000 rw-p 2b9553fec000 00:00 0
2b95549ec000-2b95549ed000 ---p 2b95549ec000 00:00 0
2b95549ed000-2b95553ed000 rw-p 2b95549ed000 00:00 0
2b95553ed000-2b95553ee000 ---p 2b95553ed000 00:00 0
2b95553ee000-2b9555def000 rw-p 2b95553ee000 00:00 0
7fffc927d000-7fffc9292000 rw-p 7ffffffe9000 00:00 0                      [stack]
7fffc93fd000-7fffc9400000 r-xp 7fffc93fd000 00:00 0                      [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffffe00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

I'm sure that this issue is involved with reading exactly from this file beacuse :

- when I comment part of `readConfiguration()` which are involved with file there is no problem
- in the same program I'm writing to other files and those file don't make any memory fail.

I run this program under valgind but there is no `Invalid write`. Moreover, under valgrind everything works fine, and there is completly no runtime error.

I'm completely confused with this error... Thanks for any help.

---

Code is compiled with g++

```
[przemek@fredek eventReporter]$ g++ -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --disable-plugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)
```

OS :

```
[przemek@fredek eventReporter]$ uname -a
Linux fredek 2.6.18-348.1.1.el5.centos.plusxen #1 SMP Tue Jan 22 19:57:41 EST 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: The code is actually correct, in a manner of speaking. The failure is just the compiler getting revenge on you for torturing it with the heinous `this->` crap.

Comment: Your file-reading loop is... weird. Why not do like `while (configFile >> line) { ... }`. Or if you really want to read lines `while (std::getline(configFile, line)) { ... }`

Comment: Also, I suggest you try to make a debug version (i.e. compiling with the `-g` flag) and then run your program in a debugger. Then the debugger will stop at the place of the crash, and you can see the call stack exactly which line you have the crash. If you can't figure out the problem yourself, then at least edit your question to include that information.

Comment: Would it crash if you comment out `delete(confOpt);`? In this code it's only place where you directly calling `free()`. Otherwise you must post more code. Because it's some method which cause crashing during deallocating memory. In my opinion code is also correct.

Comment: After comment out `delete(confOpt);` there is the same runtime error.To be honest I can post `Configuration` class, but thing looks like this that when I create `Configuration` class (and initialize `ConnectionConfigure` etc manually) and then not call `Configuration::readConfiguration();` everything is ok.